# Entity Framework - is AnyAsync() the most efficient approach? Or is Contains() better?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

My situation is I have 4 different model objects that each have a property:

```
public string UniqueId { get; private set; }
```

This UniqueId must be unique across all 4 tables (sort of a super unique key).

First, I do set it to be unique in each model (which avoids the issue of my having to handle yes there's one record with it on an update):

```
builder.HasIndex(c => c.UniqueId).IsUnique();
```

In my DbContext.SaveChanges() I am doing the following:

```
List<string> campaignUniqueIds = new();
List<string> cantonUniqueIds = new();
List<string> stateUniqueIds = new();
List<string> countryUniqueIds = new();

var upsertedCampaignUniqueIds = ChangeTracker.Entries<Campaign>()
    .Where(c => c.State == EntityState.Added || c.State == EntityState.Modified)
    .Select(c => c.Entity.UniqueId).ToList();
countryUniqueIds.AddRange(upsertedCampaignUniqueIds);
stateUniqueIds.AddRange(upsertedCampaignUniqueIds);
cantonUniqueIds.AddRange(upsertedCampaignUniqueIds);

// 3 more calls to get from the other 3 models.
```

And then I validate it with:

```
if (await Campaigns.AnyAsync(campaign => campaignUniqueIds.Contains(campaign.UniqueId)))
    throw new InvalidOperationException($"One or more of the uniqueId(s) '{string.Join(", ", campaignUniqueIds)}' is already in use by a campaign.");

// 3 more checks for the other 3 models
```

Is this the most efficient approach? I'm pretty sure building up the lists to check is good. And the fundamental approach of build 4 lists, verify each list against the appropriate table is good.

But is the call `AnyAsync()` going to give me efficient SQL? Or should I instead be crafting a call using `Contains()`?